Is the Chow variety a coarse moduli space or a fine moduli space?
In the wiki of Chow variety https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow_variety, it is writen "the Chow variety  $\mathrm{Gr}(k, d, n)$ is the fine moduli variety parametrizing all".  However, in his paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.06242v2  page 6, Janos Kollar wrote "The corresponding coarse moduli space is usually called a Chow variety".
Question: Is the Chow variety a coarse moduli space or a fine moduli space?

The Chow variety is a coarse moduli space. For instance, the Chow variety of $2$ points on $\mathbb P^2$ is the symmetric product $\mathbb P^{2(2)} = (\mathbb P^2 \times \mathbb P^2)/C_2$ where $C_2$ is the group of order $2$ acting on $\mathbb P^2 \times \mathbb P^2$ by $g \cdot (p,q) = (q,p)$ (where $g \in C_2$ is the generator). There is thus a unique point $(p,p) \in \mathbb P^{2(2)}$ corresponding to a $0$-cycle of multiplicity $2$ supported at $p$, but on the other hand one knows that any given point of $\mathbb P^2$ supports many length $2$ subschemes; e.g., if we choose coordinates $(x,y)$ on an affine chart containing $p$ so that $p = (0,0)$, then the ideal $(x^2,y)$ defines one such subscheme, but so does $(x,y^2)$ (in fact can obtain infinitely many such ideals by choosing a conic through $(0,0)$ together with its tangent line at $(0,0)$).

Dear Tabes, I'm a bit unclear what this answer is getting at. You explain that the Chow variety ignores the scheme structure on a cycle. To me, that shows it is not a coarse moduli space for subschemes, but that is not the question at issue.

My point is that it's easy to construct nonconstant families of subschemes that induce constant maps to the Chow variety hence cannot be pulled back from a universal family, but I suppose you're right, that doesn't tell us anything about families of cycles.

I believe the Chow variety is a fine moduli space, but it does not parameterize flat families of subschemes (that would be the Hilbert scheme) but rather it parameterizes "well defined families of algebraic cycles". At least that is what Kollar calls them in his book on rational curves. The fact that the Chow variety is a fine moduli space is Theorem 3.21 in that book.

I see, I must be chasing the ghost of a misremembered result. I will delete this answer in a day or two if nobody objects.

@BrianNugent: you should write this as an answer (with the warning that the result you quote is only for characterstic zero).

@BrianNugent  Interesting, it's becoming more and more confusing. Kollar himself actually gave two different statements on this question.

@BrianNugent Thank you for your reference.  But in his book on rational curves, Kollar wrote " $\operatorname{Chow}(X / S)$ is the coarse moduli space for the functor $\operatorname{Chow}(X / S)$" in page 72-(4.13.4).   What's going on?
